# Number of Rows in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a script that has a different way of doing a mySQL query to what I am used to. It starts with:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * etc .....  ");
```

then

```
while ($result = $db->fetchArray($query)) {
```

with variables shown as `$result['a']`, `$result['b']`. etc.

All I want to do is *count the rows* that are selected by the query, but **mysql_num_rows** doesn't work on `$result`.

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the count function to [count the rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT count(*) as count from (SELECT * etc .....  ) as sq  ");
$result = $db->fetchArray($query);
echo $result['count'];
```

Comment: That seems to stop the query after 1 row. Possibly because the query has an INNER JOIN? I was hoping to count the number of rows after completing the query.

Comment: it still doesn't work for me. As I have a while loop running through all the rows of the mySQL query, I've opted to increment $count by one each time the loop runs, then display $count at the end. Not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query to:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt etc .....
```

Then read the results back from the query.